# Custom Post Types not showing, custom WP_Query

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, advanced-custom-fields

My posts where showing for a while but now they are gone from my page. I see no mistakes and there's no error messages in debug mode, I really don't know why wouldn't my posts show with this code, specially when it was working before. All I did was add the Advanced Custom Fields plugin, add a few fields, link them to my posts and save. Then my posts were gone. I have disabled and deleted the plugin, remade all my posts but nothing works.

```
                <div class="artiq-slidder">

                        <ul class="artiq-slidder-ul">

                            <?php

                                $args = array(
                                        "post_type" => "piso"
                                );
                                $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

                            ?>

                            <?php if( have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

                                <li class="artiq-slidder-item">


                                <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>">  

                                     <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                                        <p> <?php the_title(); ?> </p>
                                      </a>
                                </li>

                            <?php endwhile; endif; ?>


                        </ul>

                    </div>
```

Comment: Are the posts showing in the admin? Maybe you accidentally changed the post name along the way? The `edit.php` page in the admin will show the post type. e.g. `http://example.com/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=piso` Also, in what template does this code appear? Would you edit your question and include the whole template? What is the page/post that you are looking at and what's the URL? Also, small correction to your code, it should be `if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :`

Comment: This topic is duplicate of https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/266404/custom-posts-gone-after-using-custom-fields

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please try this:

```
 <?php if( $the_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
```

Thank you

Comment: Please **[edit] your answer**, and add an explanation: **why** could that solve the problem?